# SqlAlchemy: dynamic queries

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

How to make dynamic queries in SqlAlchemy ORM (if it is a correct name for them).

I used SqlAlchemy as abstraction for database, with queries in python code, but what if I need to generate these queries dynamically, not only set the parameters of query like "id"?

For example, I need to generate query from list (table names, column names, joined columns) that links three tables like "organisation", "people", "staff". How can I do it properly?

For example, i meant this list:
  [{'table':'organisation', 'column':'staff_id'},
  {'table':'staff', 'column':'id'}]

And output for example may contain:
  organisation.id, organisation.name, organisation.staff_id, staff.id, staff.name
(name column is presented only in output, because I need simple example, recieving all columns of tables, and array must just set joins)

Comment: "I need to generate query from array of "str" elements (table names, column names, joined columns)".  That doesn't make much sense.  Please provide an example.

Comment: Hmm..  Well you have shown us the *input*, but it might be helpful to show us the intended output, either in terms of an equivalent sqlalchemy statement or the generated SQL.  I can think of several ways of interpreting your input, each with a very different meaning.

Comment: "i meant this array"... Isn't an array.  It's a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapper` on the result of a call to [`sqlalchemy.sql.join`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-multiple-tables) and/or [`sqlalchemy.select`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-class-against-arbitrary-selects).  This is roughly equivalent to using `mapper` on a database view; you can query against such classes naturally, but not necessarily create new records.  You can also use [`sqlalchemy.orm.column_property`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes) to map computed values to object attributes.  As I read your question, a combination of these three techniques should meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested, but it with the SQLAlchemy ORM, you can link tables together like:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from asgportal.database import Session

Engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:password@localhost:3306/mydatabase', pool_recycle=3600)
Base = declarative_base(bind=Engine)
session = Session()
session.configure(bind=Engine)

class DBOrganization(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_organization'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(ASGType.sa(ASGType.STRING))

class DBEmployee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_employee'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    organization_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('table_organization.id'))
    # backref below will be an array[] unless you specify uselist=False
    organization = relationship(DBOrganization, backref='employees')

Base.metadata.create_all()

# From here, you can query:
rs = session.query(DBEmployee).join(DBEmployee.organization).filter(DBOrganization.name=='my organization')

for employees in rs:
    print '{0} works for {1}'.format(employees.name,employees.organization.name)
```